# express.static not working with heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, static-files

I've got this code:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    res.sendFile(path.join( __dirname, 'assets', 'index.html' ));
});
```

But am still getting these errors:
[image]

Any idea what the heck I'm doing wrong?
(of course the files exist in the directory as shown)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a file called `./assets/css/bootstrap.css` and you configure `express.static` so that `./assets/` is the root directory, the URL should be `/css/bootstrap.css`.

Comment: bless you robert. what a basic misunderstanding on my part. thanks very much! **to clarify for others who didn't get his answer right away (as I didn't), he means to change the path in the html file, i.e. ` <link href="/css/bootstrap.css"` instead of ` <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css"`